# Why is SIN so insecure?

Tags: canada

I leaked my [SIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_insurance_number) to a landlord not knowing any better, and now I'm worried that my life can become difficult an any moment, without any reliable means of protection.

So, my question is, why is SIN made this way?

- it can apparently be used by other people with little to no verification
- it is impossible to change until there is a confirmed fraud
- the old one will still exist, requiring you to continuously monitor it

Citing https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/services/sin/protection.html:

> Your SIN is confidential. Do not use it as identification or provide it for job applications, rental applications, etc.
>
> In the wrong hands, your SIN could lead to:
>
> - an invasion of privacy
> - identify theft
> - loss of government benefits, tax refunds or bank credits
>
> If someone uses your SIN to commit fraud, it could ruin your credit rating. Someone could also use your SIN to work illegally. In this case, the Canada Revenue Agency (CRA) may expect you to pay tax on income you did not receive.

> A new SIN would mean an additional burden on you, as you would have to monitor, not only your old account and credit reports, but your new one as well on a regular and ongoing basis. Numerous SINs multiply the risk of fraud.

This design makes it hard to defend and easy to abuse.

What are the reasons it's made this way?
What are the obstacles for better verification and erasing the old SIN?
Are there any pending law changes to make it more secure?
Are there in fact protections I'm not aware of?

Comment: People are using it for things it wasn't intended to be used for. As a social security and taxpayer identification number it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

### Because it was created in 1964

It is now being used for purposes for which it was never intended in a data security environment that could not have been imagined. They are file identifiers used to streamline government business at a time when government would still have been using paper files rather than computer databases.

For what they were made for, keeping your information together and allowing disambiguation between you and someone who shares your name, they’re perfectly adequate.

They are no more or less insecure than anything else that identifies you. Your full name and date of birth will almost certainly be unique and if I have those, the inclination, and the knowledge, I can start to use that information to steal your identity. You need to keep that information confidential to be safe as well.

The problem is that people started to use the SIN to *authenticate* ann identity claim. For that, they’re totally inappropriate. But here’s the rub: a “more secure” SIN would be equally useless for that purpose - you can’t use an [identifier as an identification document](https://evolllution.com/opinions/identification-validation-authentication-compliant#:%7E:text=Identification%20does%20have%20some%20validation,official%20interaction%20with%20the%20institution.&text=Validation%20is%20showing%20something%20to%20substantiate%20the%20identity%20you%20claim%20to%20be.).

More than a decade ago, the Canadian government stopped issuing SIN cards to discourage their use as identity documents. Too late.